# looking for a MPI function in c that lets me know if all other ranks but mine are at a barrrier

Tags: c, mpi

The rank zero manages tasks to all other ranks.

Is there an mpi function similar to `MPI_Iprobe` but instead of looking for a message being sent to my rank, it was looking to see if a given rank was at a barrier.

Using this to clean up left over messages at the end of my code.

Rank zero has assigned all tasks and is ready to quit, but before it does, it needs to make sure all the other ranks are done and have sent any messages back to rank zero for entry into a log file.

Comment: Maybe Ibarrier and Test?